# Simple Odata Multiple Level Expand

Tags: c#, asp.net, odata

Working with Simple Odata and I am trying to do a multiple level expand and I am receiving a null on the second level expand. Is there are proper way to do expand with multiple levels?

Here is my example model along with how I have the function running

````
 protected override async Task<IEnumerable<Item>> InternalExecute()
        {
            using (HttpClient client = AuthHelper.GetHttpClient(_connectionString))
            {
                var oData = new ODataClient(new ODataClientSettings(client));

                var head = await oData
                     .For<Item>()
                     .Expand(x => x.account)
                     .Expand(x => x.account.parentaccountid)
                     .FindEntriesAsync();
                return head;
            }

        }


public class Item
{
    
    public string itemname { get; set; }
    public Account account { get; set; }


    public class Account
    {
        public string accountid { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }

        public ParentAccount parentaccountid { get; set; }
    }

    public class ParentAccount
    {
        public string accountid { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

}```
````

Comment: Question might make more sense if you rename the Account.parentaccountid property to something more like Account.parentaccount ...?

Code easier to read if you use CamelCase or camelCase for your properties?

Comment: Is it possible that items in the data (eg: Account 'instances') do sometimes have null values for the ParentAccount property (called 'parentaccountid')?

Comment: @Aidanapword While it is true that sometimes it does return null values I have checked again our crm that records do have a parent record and return null.